# C# Windows Application File: have no access for File.Copy

Tags: c#, system.io.file

I have a project in ANN. To make it firstly i want to clone the picture to the local directory that can be accessed everytime in order to have indexing. The directory is

> @"D:\assets\"

For the images, i'm using openfiledialog and multiselect is on.

For the container, i'm using this LOC:

```
> List<string[,]> path = new List<string[,]>();
```

The whole code is seperated. The first one is for browse and the second one is for copy the images to the directory that the first time i was mention.

**For browse button:**

```
    List<string[,]> path = new List<string[,]>();
    private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Filter = "File Extention|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.bmp";
        ofd.Multiselect = true;
        if(ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            foreach (var filename in ofd.FileNames)
            {
                imageList.Images.Add(filename, new Bitmap(filename));
                var saveFileName = Path.GetFileName(filename);
                var saveFileDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);
                lvFruit.Items.Add(saveFileName, filename);
                string[,] input = new string[,] { {saveFileDir, saveFileName } };
                path.Add(input);
            }
        }
    }
```

**For saving picture**

```
    private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String fruitname = txtFruitName.Text;
        string appPath = @"D:\assets\";
        if (txtFruitName.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Fruit Name Should be Filled");
        }
        else
        {
            int newindex = 0;

            foreach (var item in path)
            {
                newindex += 1;
                string iName = item[newindex - 1, 1].Trim();
                string iPath = item[newindex - 1, 0].Trim();
                try
                {
                    File.Copy(iPath, appPath + iName, true);
                    File.SetAttributes(appPath, FileAttributes.Normal);
                }
                catch (Exception err)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(err.ToString());
                    //MessageBox.Show("Permission error or picture is already exists");
                }
                path.Clear();
                }

            MessageBox.Show("All Picture Has Been Saved");
            lvFruit.Clear();
            txtFruitName.Text = "";
            btnDone.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

The images file is located at D:\pic and should be copied to D:\assets

The error is:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'D:\pic is denied
>      at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>      at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite, Boolean checkHost)
>      at System.IO.File.Copy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName,Boolean overwrite)
>      at Fruit_Dictionary.trainForm.btnSubmit_Click(Object sender EventArgs e) in D:\Fruit Dictionary\Fruit Dictionary\trainForm.cs:line 95

Do you know what the reason why it doesn't have any permited?

Actually i have run the program as administrator, and ofc i have check the permission in D:\pic and change it to do all permission.

I've been looking and surfing in internet for 2 days for just this reason, but i can't archieve anything. Any help will be helpful for me to accomplished this project.

Thank you :)

Comment: `new Bitmap(filename)` causes this problem.  The Bitmap class uses a memory-mapped file under the hood.  That MMF keeps a lock on the file until you call its Dispose() method.   In general very, very important because bitmaps also tend to use a lot of unmanaged memory and you can easily crash your program with OutOfMemoryException.   Using ImageList is not a great idea, but makes this easy, you can immediately dispose the bitmap after adding it to the list.

Comment: @HansPassant hmm.. actually for this code, imageList.Images.Add(filename, new Bitmap(filename)); its just for appearing the file into the listview, and you can see its working.. http://prntscr.com/kho6xy.. its just for "appearance".. not in used for copying the file..

Comment: I suggest always using the `using` keyword whenever possiable, in your case the immediate suspect is the bitmap, so you can use `using (var bmp = new Bitmap(filename))`

Comment: @styx : what do you mean about this "using"? hmm its oke for that one. but the problem is different..

Comment: @mjwills ah oke2.. so the value for File.Copy(iPath, appPath + iName, true); is File.Copy(D:\pic, D:\assets\ + a.jpg, true);

Comment: sorry the true is File.Copy(D:\pic\apple.jpg, D:\assets\ + a.jpg, true);

Answer (score -1):

try to use a process to copy your files

```
             foreach(String ImageOldPath in Paths)
             {
               try{
                ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
                info.FileName = "C:\\Windows\\system32\\xcopy.exe";
                info.Arguments = $"{ImageOldPath LocalPath} "
                Console.WriteLine(info.Arguments);
                info.UseShellExecute = false;
                info.CreateNoWindow = true;
                info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                Process proc = new Process();
                proc.StartInfo = info;
                proc.Start();
                proc.Dispose();
                }catch(Exception e){}
             }
```

**UPDATE**

- ImageOldPath is the image old path in your case its called **filename** located in your `foreach statement`
- Local path is **appPath**

Comment: So i should put the foreach inside of foreach?